# Excel VBA & Sharepoint - Blown Up File

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I recently was asked to redesign an Excel workbook that a team was using on sharepoint which was running slowly. It had 300 tabs with tonnes of hidden formulae and 30 users using it congruently. The workbook mostly gets used for data entry, and unfortunately, alternatives using a database aren't available.

I rebuilt something offline that merged 99% of the required tabs, and added a few macros to control the type of data that was being added. The file size reduced from 55MB to <2MB. After some testing, I sent this back to the team, who uploaded it to Sharepoint and started using it again.

However, for some strange reason, this file's size completely blew up - it is now at 630MB, and cannot be opened by most users anymore (all within a 6 hour window). I've been able to open a copy offline, and strangely enough, it all looks fine. There aren't any new tabs, there isn't a huge amount of new data, there are no images, charts or any embedded files that would cause the file size to blow up like this. There aren't any loops that are inserting tonnes of copies of data into any sheets, so I'm perplexed as to why this happened. Has anyone experienced something similar before? I thought VBA macros typically ran fine for files on Sharepoint, but correct me if I'm wrong.

In terms of what the VBA is doing, there is a userform that allows users to enter a single record of data at a time. The VBA that sits behind this checks the validity of the output, changes the calculation from automatic to manual, inserts a new row in a sheet, inserts the data, and changes the calculation setting back to automatic.

Is there a way to test where this hidden data supposedly lies (keeping in mind there are no hidden/super hidden tabs, and I can't find any new data in any of the sheets)? I'm fairly Excel and VBA literate, but can't for the life of me explain what has happened here.

Any help much appreciated!

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Hi all, big thanks to @Kevin - I used your method to investigate further. For some reason, one of the sheets seems to have an "active range" of A1:XFC15447. I'm not sure why this is - I've hidden all columns beyond column "I", so it could be that one of the VBA functions is unintentionally expanding all columns? Closer to the answer, but still fairly unclear to the exact root cause. As you can see in the image below, the file is so large because Excel decided it needs to remember that columns J to XFC are empty for one of the sheets... (which definitely wasn't the case with the offline version I uploaded)

[Screenshot of large sheet as xml in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQCa0.png)

Comment: If you upload the "small" version to SP and open and use it yourself as the only user, does the size blow up?

Comment: Perhaps this is something to do with Sharepoint inflating the file when it is uploaded. Ask on [Sharepoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Or try [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-file-size-of-an-excel-workbook-may-unexpectedly-increase-exponentially-b1e8e0ad-94a8-f97f-5adc-2e22798beac9)

Comment: Seems like the intention was to loop through all visible cells, or cells in columns A:I, but maybe the code has incorrectly been written to loop through all cells in the entire row, which causes them to be included in the used range, even if they are hidden. Can you narrow down the code that runs on that sheet and share it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an xlsx file, you can open it with a zip file program like 7z. Each object has its own folder, so at least you can see which objects are taking up space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Legend, thank you @kevin - I've updated the original post with what I was able to find using your method. Many thanks